# ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c

When trying to connect to a remote Oracle SQL Server using Oracle SQL Developer, I get the following error message:

Status : Failure -Test failed: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect descriptor

[image: the error]

A couple of points to note:

1. I have had this working in pretty much this configuration, but the box went bang so now can't see exactly. But I remember not having to configure Listener.ora last time around.
2. The Oracle DB Server is at a remote location, but to connect last time I had to install Oracle DB, which is what I have done this time. But I'm not trying to connect to my local DB, but the remote DB.

When I tried to change the Host in the Listener to 110.241.84.62, I can't restart the OracleOraDB12Home1TNSListener service.

[image: the services]

Googling implies that my problem lies somewhere in Listener.ora. Here are my Listener.ora and TNSNames.ora files.

Listener.ora:

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = D:\app\xoneill\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
      (ENVS = "EXTPROC_DLLS=ONLY:D:\app\xoneill\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1\bin\oraclr12.dll")
    )
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = DWH1)
      (ORACLE_HOME = D:\app\xoneill\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1)
      (GLOBAL_DBNAME = DWH1)
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
#      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 110.241.84.62)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )
```

I have tried setting the Host to the IP address of the remote server (see commented line above) but when I comment the localhost line and uncomment this then to restart the OracleOraDB12Home1TNSListener service, it Starts and Stops immediately with the following error:

[image: services error]

Actually, even just saving the Listener.ora file seems to stop the service. But I can restart fine if `HOST = localhost` but when `HOST = 110.241.84.62`, it's the above error.

TnsNames.ora:

```
# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: D:\app\xoneill\product\12.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

LISTENER_ORCL =
  (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))


ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = CLRExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = localhost)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
    )
  )

DWH1 =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 110.241.84.62)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = DWH1)
    )
  )
```

From my Googling it seems like some LSNRCTL commands were useful:

```
LSNRCTL> services
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521)))
TNS-12541: TNS:no listener
 TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00511: No listener
   64-bit Windows Error: 61: Unknown error
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1521)))
TNS-12541: TNS:no listener
 TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error
  TNS-00511: No listener
   64-bit Windows Error: 2: No such file or directory

LSNRCTL> services dwh1
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=110.241.84.62)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=DWH1)))
TNS-01189: The listener could not authenticate the user
```

Trying to connect with SQLPlus gives the same message:

```
SQL*Plus: Release 12.2.0.1.0 Production on Thu May 10 22:48:00 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Enter user-name: OBREAD@"110.241.84.62/DWH1:dedicated/OBREAD"
Enter password:
ERROR:
ORA-12514: TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in connect
descriptor
```

I feel like the answer lies somewhere in the LSNRCTL commands (I note that LSNRCTL services gives a different error of authentication) but I don't know enough to actually fully understand.

Appreciate any help.

Jono

Answer (score 2):

Your statement "The Oracle DB Server is at a remote location, but to connect last time I had to install Oracle DB, " is puzzling.  You do NOT need to install Oracle DB on your local machine to connect to a remote db.  You just need to install the Oracle *client*.

First, get rid of your listener.ora (for the time being) then restart the listener. It should start just fine with all default values, which should allow the db to self-register. Wait 60 seconds, then (on the db server) issue 'lsnrctl status'.  You should see an instance with a status of "READY". Note the SERVICE_NAME associated with it.

Next, in the tnsnames.ora on your client machine, make sure the entry 'DWH1' references the same SERVICE_NAME.

For more, see http://edstevensdba.com/oracle-tns/ora-12514-tnslistener-does-not-currently-know-of-service/

Comment: Thanks for your help... Just to confirm: getting rid of listener.ora happens on the Client, or DB server?

Comment: @Jonoracle - the listener is a _server_ side process.  There is no listener process on the client.  You may _see_ a listener.ora on your "client", but that is simply because you installed a full db software and not _just_ the client.